# Can't login parse dashboard on AWS (amazon web service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, authentication, parse-server

After creating an instance of parse server on AWS, I can see the configuration.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "mongodb://root:gzkThVPNmUS5@127.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse",
    cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
    appId: "XXXXXXXaef",
    masterKey: "XXXXX33150",
    fileKey: "XXXXXXX7073",
    serverURL: "http://XXXXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80/parse"
});
```

The problem is when I use the `serverURL` to my web browser, it asks user and password which I do know. I tried my user name and password from AWS but it does not allow me to login the parse dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

This link helps: [parse server credentials](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#using-the-aws-marketplace)

```
User: user
```

The application password is randomly generated during the first boot. This password can be viewed as follows:

1. Log in to the AWS Cloud Console.
2. In the left navigation bar, select the "Instances -> Instances" menu
   item.
3. Select your instance in the dashboard.
4. From the "Actions" drop-down menu, select the "**Get System Log**" menu
   item.
5. Review the system log until you find the application **password**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which I have just resolved:

When looking into the AWS system log for the generated username `user` (by default) and password, make sure you manually type out the password that is generated when trying to login to the Parse dashboard.

Such copy and pasted clear-text passwords sent over the insecure http protocol doesn't work, and shouldn't work.